How can i get the productID from onOrderCreated function
Question:
How can i get the productID from onOrderCreated function
Product:
Wix Studio
What are you trying to achieve:
I am trying to get the event.entity.lineItems[0]._id from onOrderCreated function but all products i used to get the id it always give me 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 id.
What have you already tried:
My reference: onOrderCreated - Velo API Reference - Wix.com
My code:
export async function wixEcom_onOrderCreated(event) {
    const productID = event.entity.lineItems[0]._id;
    console.log("Product ID: " + productID);
}

